# Socket communication between Android app and web browser

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, sockets

My Android device+app is continuously sending data every few ms, and I'd like to receive it on my web browser application that I'm building with JavaScript/HTML.

In the Android/Java app I do the following over socket:

```
//Initialize, where PORT = local ip of my laptop with web server I guess.
//and I choose an available port on my network, say 8080. 
echoSocket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

//Sending data every few ms:
JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
j.put("x", params[0]);
j.put("y", params[1]);
j.put("z", params[2]);
String jString = j.toString();
out.println(jString);
```

So I have something like `{"x": 1.0023532, "y": 2.454234, "z": 6.234583}`.

In other Java applications, I've done this communication by having my receiver application create a `ServerSocket` on the particular `PORT` used above. Then as long as I have the right local IP address for my laptop, I can do `serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);` etc.

Now, how can I accept this data in a web application (JavaScript/HTML)? I've heard of websockets but have no idea how to initialize and use for this purpose - hopefully it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Are you suggesting that your server receiving the data will only run with html/javascript?

Comment: Can I not receive my socket data directly in the browser?

Comment: Well you could but you would need a server to be communicating with the andoird app then the browser communicating with the server. I dont belive you can run server sockets with javascript. You need something like nodeJs, java or maybe php (I would shy away from doing this in php given the ammount of data your sending over) - if you have a language preference I could give you an example if you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think its possible to send data directly to the browser without a middle man (server). If you want to create a fast and easy server to ping data back and forth I would have some fun with NodeJs. I havent gotten a chance to ever use the stuff but I did have some fun playing with it. It could be something to look into expecially if your just pinging data back and forth between clients.

I watched this video "[Introduction to Node.js with Ryan Dahl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jo_B4LTHi3I)" a while ago and he showed a basic example that does pretty much what your talking about. Just a thought, plus it would be a fun and fast implementation.

On a side note I do believe Amazon AWS has a instance for Node JS if you want to bring it to a live server. Im pretty sure you can setup a micro instance for no cost.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into using NodeJS.